# PDO not inserting - error code 00000

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an issue with my INSERT query, $pdo->execute return false, with error code 00000

```
Query
string 'INSERT INTO module_test (img_name, description, priority) VALUES(:img_name, :description, :priority)' (length=100)

errorInfo() return:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '00000' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null
```

Code:

```
private function Init($query, $parameters = "")
{
    # Connect to database
    if (!$this->bConnected) {
        $this->Connect();
    }
    try {
        # Prepare query
        $this->sQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

        # Add parameters to the parameter array 
        $this->bindMore($parameters);

        # Bind parameters
        if (!empty($this->parameters)) {
            foreach ($this->parameters as $param => $value) {

                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                switch ($value[1]) {
                    case is_int($value[1]):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value[1]):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value[1]):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                }
                // Add type when binding the values to the column
                $this->sQuery->bindValue($value[0], $value[1], $type);
            }
        }
        # Execute SQL 
        var_dump($query);
        var_dump($this->sQuery->execute());
        var_dump($this->sQuery->errorInfo());
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        # Write into log and display Exception
        echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage(), $query);
        die();
    }

    # Reset the parameters
    $this->parameters = array();
}
public function query($query, $params = null, $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $query = trim(str_replace("\r", " ", $query));

    $this->Init($query, $params);

    $rawStatement = explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+|\t+|\n+/", " ", $query));

    # Which SQL statement is used 
    $statement = strtolower($rawStatement[0]);
    if ($statement === 'select' || $statement === 'show') {
        return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
    } elseif ($statement === 'insert' || $statement === 'update' || $statement === 'delete') {
        return $this->sQuery->rowCount();
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
public function insert($table, $keyValue)
{
    $fieldString = '';
    $valueString = '';
    $i           = 1;
    foreach ($keyValue as $key => $currKeyValue) 
    {
        $fieldString .= $key;
        $valueString .= ':'.$key;
        if($i != count($keyValue))
        {
            $fieldString .= ', ';
            $valueString .= ', ';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $query       = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$fieldString.') VALUES('.$valueString.')';
    $this->query($query, $keyValue);
}
```

Parameters array

```
F:\Dev\wamp\wamp64\www\include\class\Database.class.php:216:
array (size=3)
  'img_name' => string 'ttt1' (length=4)
  'description' => string 'ttt1' (length=4)
  'priority' => int 0
```

I already try this query in phpmyadmin and everything worked well.

If someone know how to solve this?

thanks

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Error code 00000 means that the query way successfully executed

Comment: Yes i know, but i dont know why no one line has been added

Comment: Wrapping PDO in an object wrapper is a bit like having an ashtray on a motor bike. You have to know what you are doing before you try using it. PDO works just great using its existing object.

Comment: This is not the problem here, select statement work great with that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PDO is reported not to fill the `errorInfo` property in certain circumstances.

Instead, you have to make it throw an exception, which is the most reliable way to get the error message. To do so, in your constructor, add this line

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Also note that your class is a genuine example of all the mistakes one could make writing a PDO wrapper. I compiled the most popular mistakes in an article, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes) and your class **contains every single one of them.**

Comment: I already set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.

For my class something like that woul'be better?  https://github.com/wildantea/php-pdo-mysql-helper-class

Comment: If PDO doesn't throw an exception then there is no error and INSERT actually worked. Or may be you managed to do something extremely strange in your class. Why not to learn raw PDO inserts before starting with wrappers?

Comment: As of the wrapper from the link you posted, it's even worse than yours - it's full of SQL injections.

Comment: How it's possible with PDO and prepared statement? if you bind  all parameters it's safe no?

Comment: *IF* you bind, it is safe. But the guy who wrote that wrapper don't bother to bind. Besides, sometimes you just cannot bind. If you read the article I posted for you, you will learn how it's possible.

Comment: I resolve this issue with your wrapper https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper 
No issue with the same querry / Parameters, strange...
Thanks for your advices

Comment: I am glad it helped. Feel free to ask if you will have any questions.